# Ubuntu extremely slow (dualboot / GTX 960M / Lenovo Y50-70)

Tags: dual-boot, drivers, nvidia, 17.04

So I've dual booted windows 10 and Ubuntu 17.xx on my Lenovo y50-70 with a NVidia 960M (OR 860M) graphics card. The only way the install would work, was with the "nomodeset" flag on. It seems buggy because my screen freezes every time the install finishes and I click restart. I then had to do force a shutdown. (I've installed it like 5 times)

-
Anyways Ubuntu is unusably slow. I can see every frame transition and it takes many seconds for a change on the screen to appear.

-
I don't know much about ppas and repos, so this next bit of info might sound off. I've tried installing graphics drivers straight from an Nvidia ppa, generic x-org drivers, and the NVidia-current-update method. All of them on restart either brought me to a purple screen or an endless login loop.

-
Idk what to do. I don't need to use my NVidia graphics card for Ubuntu, just the intel chip, if that's possible. I can only boot into Linux when I have nomodeset turned on

-
Also, at times it not slow at all, though it seems rare. (like when I go from windows to Ubuntu).

-
What is wrong?

Comment: There are many things wrong: There's no "Nvidia PPA" and the `nvidia-current`package is actually for legacy hardware only. So, right now, I'm tempted to suggest a full Ubuntu reinstall because you already messed too much with it. But you can try: Keep the `nomodeset` to boot, open the terminal and purge all the wrong drivers: `sudo apt purge nvidia*`. Then, open Additional drivers and select the recommended one, apply and reboot. If it doesn't work, reinstall Ubuntu and follow the correct procedure from the start.

Comment: Ive installed 5 separate times, each trying a different method. Ive done a purge nvidia. I didnt select additional drivers though. Why do you think my system is so slow?

Comment: It's slow because it needs the correct Nvidia drivers.

Comment: Turns out im using xorg's driver already. The nvidia option is also there

Comment: Ive switched to the nvidia driver and still nothing.

Comment: @MichaelBay what makes you think the OP didn't follow the "correct" procedure? Many machines won't boot Ubuntu if you don't use the `nomodeset` option and that's a reasonable thing to do. I don't see why reinstalling would help. jsm18, please `edit` your question and post the output of `inxi -G` (you might need to install `inxi` with `sudo apt install inxi` first).

Comment: @terdon I think I've explained it throughly in the other comment. Of course nomodeset is probably needed (and I mentioned that) but then installing who knows how much different drivers version is a recipe for disaster. And, again, `nvidia-current` instalsl an old drivers meant for legacy hardware only. A GTX960M is not legacy and actually requires very **new** Nvidia drivers.  What can be done I also described (purge nvidia drivers and attempt to install some proper version) but that might not work either...